# each run twice for ul items

Tags: loops, jquery

I use `$.each` to calculate the width of ul items (li tags) . 
in this sample `$.each` work without any problem, but when I use in my code the `$.each` run twice (I mean, if I had 4 items, `$.each` will run 8 times)

can I use `for` to create a loop for checking the li width ?

the code is :
http://jsfiddle.net/rmsvf/

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Your fiddle apparently runs 8 times for 8 items. You probably have more `<li>` tags in your actual code and are not selecting them specifically enough.

Comment: why do you say it runs twice? I see that the result is 1600, which matches the 8 elements x 200 px. So it's working fine?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my question in this sample the width is true but exactly this code in my program run twice !

Comment: Have you tried giving the elemts you want to count a class as I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. `8 li * 200px = 1600px`

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine for me. My guess would've been too that there may be more li elements in your actual code.
Give the li elements *you want to count* a class `<li class="ClassName">Li Element</li>` and call your each function like this just to test:

`$('.ClassName').each(`